# Admob implementation in Phonegap for Android app

Tags: android, cordova, admob

I converted one jquery script into Android app , Now i want to add admob into it , is this possible ???

Comment: When you say your converted a jquery script, what do you mean? Does your app run in the Android browser or is it a standalone Java app?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Google have since [updated their documentation](http://support.google.com/adsense/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=68724) to forbid using AdSense in a mobile application:

> "The use of AdSense for mobile in a mobile application is a violation of AdSense policies. A mobile application constitutes any downloadable application, even if a WebView is used to display the ad. Any AdSense for mobile ad units found in mobile applications will be disabled. If you’re looking for an advertising solution for your mobile application, please sign up for AdMob, Google’s leading mobile advertising display product."

The solution is to use the [dedicated PhoneGap plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/In-App-Advertisements).

Comment: I'd recommend coupling this together with a call to the PhoneGap Network API to first check if the device has a network connection, otherwise this won't work.

Comment: The "Smart Phone Web App" option has been removed from AdMob. It appears the only solution for using AdMob, keeping in line with Goolge's T & C's, is to use native integration as opposed to a JavaScript solution. Example phone gap Android code: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/In-App-Advertisements - I guess that we'll need to take the plunge to extend to different platforms: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_getting-started_index.md.html - I can only guess this is being enforced to make the distinction between apps and web sites (mobile flavour) (the latter should use AdSense).

Comment: @PhilipMurphy but surely the same principle applies to AdSense mobile ads? AdSense mobile is essentially the same product as AdMob.

Comment: @BenParsons "The use of AdSense for mobile in a mobile application is a violation of AdSense policies. A mobile application constitutes any downloadable application, even if a WebView is used to display the ad. Any AdSense for mobile ad units found in mobile applications will be disabled. If you’re looking for an advertising solution for your mobile application, please sign up for AdMob, Google’s leading mobile advertising display product." -- http://support.google.com/adsense/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=68724

Comment: @TalkLittle, seriously, downvote on an answer given almost 2 1/2 years ago? You think maybe something might have changed in the time since..? Why don't you edit my answer to update the information, rather than downvoting?

Comment: @BenParsons This answer is obsolete, and by leaving this info here, it can cause someone's app to be banned by breaking Google's terms. I'd suggest you remove the answer if you don't want downvotes.

Comment: @TalkLittle if you want to edit one's question shouting warnings, at least attach a source to it.

Comment: @TalkLittle so you are suggesting that each day, I go through my old answers to see if there has been any change in circumstance in the intervening time? SO is effectively a wiki - YOU can update my answer with the correct information, this would be far more constructive than downvoting and leaving a comment. As it stands you are being extremely childish.

Comment: @BenParsons Why so defensive? No need to spend extra effort monitoring past questions, as evidently you carefully watch your downvotes and comments already. The community informs you of answers gone bad. Anyway I've been following SO guidelines all along: 1) Downvoted answer, SO suggests I comment, so I do. 2) You comment suggesting I edit, which is reasonable. I tried, twice, but apparently Shimmy didn't like my phrasing, so the edits didn't make it. This is no longer worth my time to fix. It's up to you to delete it, and help future users who stumble here, which would waste much less time.

Comment: @BenParsons I see you've edited the answer with updated info regarding their policies, which I and future users will appreciate. You've earned my upvote.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the android native code (I could recommend doing this instead of using mobile site code).  There is a great explanation on how to do it on on phonegap.wiki.com, see [this](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/51172827/HOW%20TO:%20Add%20admob%20ads%20to%20your%20phonegap%20application)

Also check out this answer on stackoverflow, it prevents a bug where your local storage gets deleted:
[Android + HTML5(LocalStorage) + Admob: Bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850103/android-html5localstorage-admob-bug)