# Android + HTML5(LocalStorage) + Admob: Bug?

Tags: android, html, cordova, admob, local-storage

I am developing an Phonegap app(Android), which uses javascript/HTML5
localStorage. The app works fine, however when I add the Admob to
the app, the localStorage not work. Meaning
the stored values are delete when the app is force closed or the phone
is restarted.

```
public class TestActivity extends DroidGap {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

        // ADMOB: If comment, work.
        /*
        LinearLayout layout = super.root;
        AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, **MY_CODE_ADMOB**);
        layout.addView(adView);
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
        adView.loadAd(request);
        */
    }
}
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 10):

You have to delay the code that launches the ad by a few seconds...below worked for me.

```
public class youActivity extends DroidGap {
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            doStuff();
        }
    }, 5000); 
}
private void doStuff() {
    final String MY_AD_UNIT_ID = "yourAD_UNIT_ID";
    AdView adView; 
    // Create the adView 
    adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, MY_AD_UNIT_ID); 
    LinearLayout layout = super.root; // this is the only change from the sample 
    // Add the adView to it 
    layout.addView(adView); 
    // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad 
    adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
}
}
```

Comment: private Handler mHandler = new Handler(); showing "Handler cannot be resolved by type" error in Eclipse. Please help me

Comment: @user1184211 can't we just change the localstorage db name so conflicts would disappear? I tried to use sql as you suggested but I cannot get values from it as its asinchronous :(

Answer (score 0):

I had exeprienced the same issues in getting AdMob working together with storage using Phonegap/Cordova and a sqlite file with my db being copied from the apk into the db location.
I have tried the delay solution mentioned here. My observation was that to access the database with the correct data the `window.openDatabase("xxx", "1.0", "xxx", 1000000);` needs to be done before the AdRequest is created. This wasn't a solution in my case, since opening the connection again on another page where it is neded will result in the database being empty.

The way I solved this issue was with a plugin available at https://github.com/lite4cordova/Cordova-SQLitePlugin. It works exactly the same as the websql with the exception of opening the database in a different way (not much to rewrite if you have your queries already written). If you open it using:

```
var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "DB"});
```

it will use a DB.db file rather than the default 0000000000000001.db. This should prevent conflicts with AdMob. 2 things to watch out for:

1. The plugin needs ondeviceready to be trigerred not just document to
   be loaded to open the db.
2. If you are coping an sqlite file you ship
   with the apk, make sure to adjust the location where you copy it to.

Comment: can't we just change the localstorage db name so conflicts would disappear? I tried to use sql as you suggested but I cannot get values from it as its asinchronous :(