# Localstorage overwritten with Cordova plus admob

Tags: android, cordova, admob

When admob code is initialized in a Phonegap/Cordova app that makes use of localStorage, the localStorage seems to get overridden by the admob ad view.

Here's the code for initialization of the admob code (using v6.2.1 of the SDK) in a Cordova 2.2 app::

```
public class Foo extends DroidGap
{
    private AdView adView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);

        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html", 3000);

        adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.SMART_BANNER, "AD_MOB_ID");
        root.addView(adView);
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
        request.setTesting(true);
        adView.loadAd(request);
    }
```

The ad gets loaded but the localStorage which I use to maintain the session of the user seems to get cleared and the login page is displayed. When I comment the admob initialization code, the localStorage gets reverted and the user's session is back.

As per the instructions on [1] and [2], I have added a handler::

```
public class Foo extends DroidGap
{
    private AdView adView;
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);

        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html", 3000);

        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                loadAdmob();
            }
        }
    }

    private void loadAdmob()
    {
          adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.SMART_BANNER, "AD_MOB_ID");
          root.addView(adView);
          AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
          request.setTesting(true);
          adView.loadAd(request);
    }
```

This tries loading the ads 10 seconds later but I get the following message in logcat::

```
adRequestUrlHtml: <html>...
Received ad url: <url: ...
Request Scenario: Offline with no buffered ads.
Network is unavailable. Aborting ad request.
onFailedToReceiveAd(A network error occurred.)
```

I can confirm that there is no problem with the network connection (because the rest of the data in the app gets displayed and is fetched over the network) and yet the ad does not display. Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug? A workaround for this problem will be helpful.

[1] [Android + HTML5(LocalStorage) + Admob: Bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850103/android-html5localstorage-admob-bug)
[2] https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/In-App-Advertisements

Comment: Why is 3000 value part of loadUrl and not part of the handler?  Have you tried changing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experienced the same problem with receiving the network error when introducing the delay (perhaps due to running on another thread, it loses the necessary permissions to query the network.)

The way I solved this was to override onAttachToWindow() and invoke the adMob initialization from in there, and removing the handler code altogether. It has the side effect of being near instant with no delay as well.

```
@Override public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();

    doAdMob();
};

private void doAdMob() {
    adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "ID");

    LinearLayout layout = super.root;

    layout.addView(adView);
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest();

    request.addTestDevice("ID");

    adView.loadAd(request);
}
```

I'm using Cordova 2.5 btw.

UPDATE: AdMod still corrupts the localstorage, but it's loaded by the time AdMob has a chance to wipe it out. However, on a subsequent reload, it will be reset. I've since resolved this behavior by adding

```
window.setTimeout(saveSettings, 5000);
```

after I've loaded my localStorage settings. This is highly hackish of course.. but seems to do the trick so far. Also note, I've only been using the test ads for AdMob.

Comment: hi man. I face the same problem and Im trying since 3 days to get it working.. I don't really understand what you mean. Could you please exemplify a littl bit more? Do you override onAttachedToWindow and you save the adMob settings through window.setTimeout(saveSettings, 5000); and after you load the localstorage data? I'll be very gratefull for an answer!!