# Phonegap + Admob clear HTML5 local Storage

Tags: html, cordova, admob, local-storage

i have done an Andriod App using Phonegap, HTML5 LocalSorage and JS. All works fine.
But since i add Admob, my app clears LocalStorage every time the app gets fully loaded or the phone getting restarted.

like recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850103/android-html5localstorage-admob-bug)  and also on [Github](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/In-App-Advertisements) I use a delay to prevent clearing.
But in my Case its still clearing the LocalStorage.
All works fine without Admob.

Any other suggestions how to prevent Admob from clearing localStorage?
Or other a simple alternative to prevent localStorage?

Thanks for help!

Comment: I managed to install on my phone and see LocalSorage is not getting clead. Only geting "blocked". if i disable network connection all works fine (of course exept the Ads). Any suggestions how to solve this?

Comment: CHeck this if u haven't already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850103/android-html5localstorage-admob-bug

Comment: @JonnyB hy man.. Have you solved your issue? if ye, how?

Comment: @user1184211 hi I tried deaying init but it still dont work, i have other bugs, what other mothod exist to avoid this localstorage block?