# phonegap 2.0 with admob/iads

Tags: ios, cordova, admob, iad

I've been searching for hours for a  guide/tutorial on how to implement either admob or iads in an iOS app build with PhoneGap 2.0. So far I've been searching in vain. The closest I have gotten to an answer is this:

http://iphone.keyvisuals.com/iphonedev/implementing-admob-ads-in-a-phonegap-project-for-ios-no-plugins-required/

I dont have any objective-c experience and in the above mentioned link I can get past 3rd step. I have tried to download the demo and look at the code, but the app can't even be built. Probably because I'm using PhoneGap 2.0 and not an older version.

Are any of you guys able to guide me, or know of any helpful links for this to succeed?

Comment: See this question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428022/admob-implementation-in-phonegap-for-android-app/4461871#4461871

Comment: Not marking as duplicate because the methods are different, but I suspect you would be better off using the mobile web tags than the native tags. (This is explained in the link.)

Comment: It seems like the link refers to android and not iOS? Or have I missed something?

Comment: Did you read my comment above or the linked answer? The suggestion is to not use the NATIVE (this means android/iOS) ad tags but to embed the ads in your HTML that is going in the contained app. This way you avoid editing the phonegap container and can integrate your ads more easily.

Comment: Ye, but it seems like the answer which is a link just refers to: http://www.admob.com/my_sites/create_site where I can create an "Add Site/App" (if im logged in) but it still requires med to download an SDK an write native code in xcode?

Answer (score 0):

How about using this [plugin](https://github.com/smithimage/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/AdMob) from github? Looks like getting it setup shouldn't be too bad.

Comment: Could you provide any usage example? It's really hard to know what I should pass into 'options' of the various methods. Having no previous experience with objective c, reading the source does not help..